# Need to read data from Kafka and Hive in one query via Flink(FlinkSQL)

Tags: apache-kafka, hive, apache-flink, flink-sql

I want to run a heterogeneous query in Flink to read several tables from Kafka (the data is written in Kafka so that you can join them via FlinkSQL), and several tables from Hive, in one query.

I can run queries separately for Kafka and Hive, but not in one request, because when connecting to the Hive catalog, previously created tables(for read data from Kafka) become unavailable.

How can I use FlinkSQL to read data from both Kafka and Hive in a single query?